# What's an equivalent in python of stringification C preprocessor macro #

Tags: python, macros, stringify

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html allows to stringify argument (before evaluation), which is useful for debugging. How would we do it in python?
eg:

```
def prettyprint(a):
  #requires special function stringify
  print(stringify('a') + ':' + str(a));

def test():
  prettyprint(1+2)
  # will print: 1+2:3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this without using strings. The C preprocessor really only processes text, so `stringify` is placing the expression in quotes and the rest is `eval`

```
def prettyprint(a):
    print( a + ':' + str( eval(a) ) )

>>> prettyprint('1+2')
1+2:3
```

If you don't use strings, then the expression will be evaluated before the call and `prettyprint` has no way to figure out how the `3` it received came to be.